# Concatenate Excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file

I've a Excel with 3 sheets and one with 2 sheets. I would like to have at the end an Excel file with 5 sheets. The problem I'm facing is that the first Excel file has pictures and tables, so when I tried to concatenate the 2 files that content disappear...

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

writer = ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")

for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    (_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    (f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
        df_excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        df_excel.to_excel(writer, f_short_name+'_'+sheet_name, index=False)

writer.save()
```

This is the solution that gave me the best results however it's not good enough. I think the problem is with pandas but I don't know what else to use. Any ideas?

Comment: The `pandas.read_excel` probably just extracts text within cells and ignores rich contenct like pictures and tables. Rather than work from `pandas`, you're probably better off working directly with an excel library such as [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: openpyxl does now preserve images in files.